# My Jenkins confluence publishing plugin does not work

Tags: jenkins, publishing, confluence, jenkins-plugins

I have a little issue with my development infrastructure. I have a Jenkins CI and I would like to use the Jenkins Confluence publishing plugin to publish the artifacts on a wiki page. I have followed all the steps within the [plugin home page](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Confluence+Publisher+Plugin) but it does not work.
All configuration have been verified (credentials, etc.)...but still, it does not work. Jenkins even check automatically if the credentials provided are correct and if it can access the target confluence page.

instead, after the build I have the following error :

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 15 seconds
Archiving artifacts
[confluence] Unable to locate page: ARTIFACT/App+Artifact+Page.
[confluence] Check that the page still exists.  If the Space and/or Page name contain build-time parameters, check that the parameter(s) are set to the proper value(s).
Finished: SUCCESS
```

ARTIFACT is the space name and App Artifact Page the page name.

Any help would be appreciated
Thanks in advance

Comment: Never mind : I found out! if you stumble upon it then NEVER NEVER NEVER put the + sign on the page name (like above App+Artifact+Page) (when configuring the publishing in Jenkins CI UI) even though your page name contains white spaces. So here it should be "App Artifact Page" (without the quotes of course)

Comment: Please consider ['officially' answering your question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with those pluses in page name. So when your page name is `Page Names With Pluses` then url in the web browser shows:

```
http://confluence.example.com/display/Space/Page+Names+With+Pluses
```

**Don't put** those pluses in Jenkins' configuration but **put** `Page Names With Pluses` and it'll work.